# Gradient Computation/Assembly Very Slow

Tags: openmdao

I'm implementing an existing MATLAB optimization code in Python using OpenMDAO.

The basic problem structure from `openmdao summary` is:

```
============== Problem Summary ============
Groups:              14
Components:          70
Max tree depth:       5

Design variables:            7   Total size:      121

Nonlinear Constraints:      12   Total size:      936
    equality:                0                      0
    inequality:             12                    936

Linear Constraints:          0   Total size:        0
    equality:                0                      0
    inequality:              0                      0

Objectives:                  1   Total size:        1

Input variables:           357   Total size:    41451
Output variables:          271   Total size:    31855

Total connections: 357   Total transfer data size: 41451
```

At the top level, there are 5-10 components for evaluating constraints and objectives, there is a group where the DOF variables are being defined/parsed (`SplineComp`) and a large group where the bulk of the computations are being done (contains one group with two levels, one group with one level, and a bunch of components).  This is basically the same structure as the MATLAB code.  On the MATLAB side, I am computing analytical gradients at the problem level, but calling the large group 14 times for finite difference gradients of that portion.  In Python, I'm using a mix of hand calculated gradients and automatic differentiation tools of the components inside that large group and its subgroups.

I've verified that the results match between Python and MATLAB for a prescribed set of inputs and `check_partials`/`check_totals` give satisfactory results in Python, I'm now stumped at the speed comparisons in benchmarking.

In MATLAB, the gradient computation takes **~14x** longer than a standalone evaluation of the objective/constraint, which is as expected given the finite difference approach used.

In Python, the compute_totals takes **~25-50x** longer than run_model.  This is perplexing to me as I'd expect much better performance since there's zero finite difference involved here.  I'm not expecting `compute_totals` to be the same speed as run_model, but it's more than an order of magnitude slower than I expected.

I ran the command line profiling (iprof) and unsurprisingly most of the time is being spent in solve_linear, but after using the python profile tool, it's showing nearly half the time is spent in `dictionary_jacobian`.

I tried looking into using the coloring feature to improve the computation time, but it doesn't seem to be finding the actual sparsity of the jacobian (reports ~64% non-zero compared to ~6% actual):
[image]

I've verified that all my custom components are using sparse partial definitions through the rows/cols option of declare_partials (do certain built in components not use sparse definitions that would cause this? I'm using a few inside of the large group for convenience)  I know the hackathon findings (https://github.com/OpenMDAO/RevHack2020/blob/master/solution_approaches/how_big.md) suggest I should have one large component instead of multiple small components, but that'll be hard to implement here without losing a good chunk of the flexibility I need for activating different features inside that group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the flexibility then keep the components the size you have them.

`Dictionary Jacobian` implies that you're not taking advantage of the `DirectSolver` which is needed to get really good performance for models of your size. This includes the use of the assembled Jacobian, which is also needed for really fast derivatives.

Try setting the `DirectSolver` to the linear solver at the top of your model like this:

`prob.model.linear_solver = om.DirectSolver()`

For generality, I should not the following:

- You can only use `DirectSolver` on a serial group (but that serial group could be part of a larger distributed model).
- You can use a `DirectSolver` on a sub-group of a model. Depending on model structure, this may be faster [(See section 5.3 of this paper)](http://file:///Users/jsgray/Downloads/Gray2019_Article_OpenMDAOAnOpen-sourceFramework.pdf)
- DirectSolver works with an assembled jacobian (as opposed to the `DictionaryJacobian` referenced in question). This is down in the weeds, but in the vast majority of cases you want a sparse assembled jacobian for the direct solver. Very occasionally a dense assembly is better. That is controlled through [system option `assembled_jac_type`](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/67a803d09d1dd8394871d26ee741e85bd053df08/openmdao/core/system.py#L326-L328) which defaults to `csc` (a sparse format). You might try dense as a test -- but again, `csc` is very likely to be fastest.

Comment: Swapping to DirectSolver seems to marginally improve the speed.  I'm seeing ~25-30x for gradient v. obj/constraint evaluation.  At least the variability is less (was even seeing 75x for LinearRunOnce).  This still seems very slow to me though.  Based on the MATLAB code, I was expecting somewhere around 3-5x relative cost by removing the the finite difference.

Thanks for the reference (the link points to your local copy, but I think I have a copy of that paper).  I'll review that again.

I tried playing with the assembled_jac_type awhile back, but ran into memory issues.

Comment: If u can provide some test code, we can take a look. Save that it's hard to give better advise

Comment: Your advice got me pointed down the right path.  Swapping to `DirectSolver` moved the focus to other portions of the code. After spending more time looking into it today, I'm now seeing some bottlenecks in the AD partials that weren't as apparent before, so I have some more work to do there before drawing further conclusions.  I may have underestimated the expense of those from the previous profiling I did.  `openmdao iprof_totals` is giving me a better overall picture than `python -m profile` since I was missing the forest for the trees in the more granular results.  Thanks for your help!